# Show that $X_n \to 0$ in probability under given condition.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Let $k > 0$. Suppose that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N: \forall n \geq N: P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon k$$

Show that $X_n \xrightarrow{P}{ 0}$.

Attempt:

We have to show:

$$\forall \tilde{\epsilon} > 0: \lim_n P(|X_n| \geq  \tilde{\epsilon}) = 0$$

This is equivalent with showing that

$$\forall \tilde{\epsilon} > 0: \forall \epsilon \in ]0, \tilde{\epsilon}[: \exists N: \forall n \geq N : P(|X_n| \geq  \tilde{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon k$$

So, let's show this.

Let $\tilde{\epsilon} > 0$ and take $\epsilon \in ]0 , \tilde{\epsilon}[$. Choose $N$ such that $P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon k$ whenever $n \geq N$. Then, if $n \geq N$, we have

$$P(|X_n| \geq \tilde{\epsilon}) \leq P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon k$$

and the claim follows.

Is this correct?

Comment: "This is equivalent with showing that$$\forall \tilde{\epsilon} > 0: \forall \epsilon \in ]0, \tilde{\epsilon}[: \exists N: \forall n \geq N : P(|X_n| \geq  \tilde{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon k"$$ No, that is not the definition of convergence on probability.

Comment: But it is equivalent with it?

Comment: I can restrict to small epsilon and must be able to make everything smaller than epsilon times a certain constant.

Comment: Demonstrating that equivalence is exactly what your proof is supposed to do.

Comment: It is standard epsilon delta right? I can restrict to smaller epsilon. That's sufficient and getting it smaller than epsilon*k is also sufficient.

Comment: Okay, now write that up. THAT is your proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\delta]=0$ for all $\delta>0$. Fix $\delta>0$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N_\varepsilon$ such that
$\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\frac{\varepsilon\wedge \delta}{k}]<\varepsilon\wedge\delta$ whenever $n\geq N$ (This can be done by the conditions in the hypothesis). Consequently, if $n\geq N_\varepsilon$
$$ \mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\delta]\leq \mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\frac{\varepsilon\wedge\delta}{k}]<\varepsilon\wedge\delta\leq\varepsilon$$
This shows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>\delta]=0$ for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: Thanks. Is my own proof correct though?

Comment: your arguments is almost correct, you just need to control your $\epsilon k$ in terms of the free quantifier $\widetilde{\epsilon}$.

Comment: What do you mean? Where exactly is the flaw in my argument?

Comment: Your equivalence is not correct; however, you could say that: it is enough to show that $$\forall \tilde{\epsilon} > 0: \forall \epsilon \in ]0, \tilde{\epsilon}[: \exists N: \forall n \geq N : P(|X_n| \geq  \tilde{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon k$$ What you are require to prove is: $$\forall \tilde{\epsilon} > 0: \forall \epsilon >0: \exists N: \forall n \geq N : P(|X_n| \geq  \tilde{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon k$$